# Releasing object on different pointer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For example:

```
MyClass *obj1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
MyClass *obj2 = [obj1 retain];
```

and release it with

```
[obj2 release];
[obj2 release];
```

Is it legal to do this? Will the object will be released properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it'll work fine. You're calling release on the same object, no matter which pointer variable you use to do so.

Looks a bit weird though.

And, a common idiom would be

```
[obj1 release], obj1 = nil;
[obj2 release], obj2 = nil;
```

which clearly wouldn't work if you used obj2 in both lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can check easily enough by testing if `obj1 == obj2`.